# Let $G$ be a group, and $A,B$ normal commutative subgroups of $G$. If the $A \cap B = \{e\}$, does this isomorphism hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $A,B$ normal commutative subgroups of $G$. True or False

a) $\forall a \in A: \forall b \in B: ab = ba$

b) $\forall a \in A: \forall b \in B: aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A \cap B$

c) If $A \cap B = \{e\}$, then $G \cong \frac{G}{A} \oplus \frac{G}{B}$

d) If $A \cap B = \{e\}$, then $AB$ is a commutative subgroup of $G$ and is isomorphic to $A+B$.

---

My answers:

a) False: take the group $D_4$ and let $A = \{e, a, a^2, a^3\}, B = \{e, b\}$. Then it holds that $ab = ba^2 \neq ba$.

b) True, since $A,B$ are normal subgroups, $aba^{-1} \in B$, so that $aba^{-1} \cdot b^{-1} \in B$, and $ba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A$, so that $a\cdot ba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A$,  which means that $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A \cap B$.

c) I am not sure how to prove this one.

d) False, take the example from a). Then $A \cap B = \{e\}$, but $AB$ is not commutative since $ab \neq ba$ and $ae \in AB, eb \in AB$.

I need help solving c, and are my answers for the other questions correct?

Comment: You are correct that a) is false, but your counterexample does not work, because $B$ is not normal in $G$. Instead, you could take $B = \{e,b,a^2,a^2b\}$. Also d) is true, because b) implies that $AB$ is commutative when $A \cap B = \{e\}$.

Comment: Ohh wow yes I do see. Thank you for noticing my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** okay, so, without requiring $AB = G$ we don't need to complicate ourselves that much. An isomorphism such as in $(c)$ would five $|G| = |G|^2/|A||B|$. So $|A||B| = |G|$. This need not be the case, for example, pick $A$ and $B$ of coprime order in a larger abelian group.

E.g. $G= \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_3 \oplus \Bbb Z_5$, $A = \Bbb Z_2, B = \Bbb Z_3$.

If we insist on having $AB =G$, then the result is true.

Indeed, since $A \cap B  = 1$ we have $G = A \times B$, via $(a,b) \mapsto ab$. The map sends $A \times 1$ to $A$ and $1 \times B$ to $B$, hence $G/A = A \times B / A \times 1 = B, G/B = A \times B / 1 \times B = A$ and
thus

$$
G = A \times B = G/A \times G/B.
$$

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately the example in a) does not work, because $B$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you maybe have a tip for c)?

Comment: I think we're okay now, although after the previous mistake a sanity check would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Ohhh I see, thank you so much for your help!